# Get thumbnail image for Yahoo video? (python)

Tags: python, video, yahoo

The question has a similar intent as this question:

[Get img thumbnails from Vimeo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1361149/get-img-thumbnails-from-vimeo)

but that one was for vimeo.

So, I have a url for the yahoo video, is there any way I could get the standard thumbnail using the url?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, Yahoo supports oembed. So, you can take the video url e.g., 
http://video.yahoo.com/watch/5202550/13742849 and pass it on to their oembed service like this:

http://video.yahoo.com/services/oembed?url=http://video.yahoo.com/watch/5202550/13742849

The response to that will contain the thumbnail image url.