# Get img thumbnails from Yahoo! Screen Video Player (not older webplayer)

Tags: api, video, thumbnails, yahoo, yahoo-api

I am trying to get yahoo! screen video's image thumbs to embed on my website like we can easily do in other websites ( [Get img thumbnails from Vimeo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1361149/get-img-thumbnails-from-vimeo), [How do I get a YouTube video thumbnail from the YouTube API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068344/how-to-get-thumbnail-of-youtube-video-link-using-youtube-api), etc.).

There used to be a sugestion: [Get thumbnail image for Yahoo video? (python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3262532/get-thumbnail-image-for-yahoo-video-python) but it doesn't seem to work now with the new Yahoo! Screen.

Some quick searching on the Internets led me to Y!'s very own online help: http://help.yahoo.com/l/in/yahoo/video/using/using005.html;_ylt=Aj3rNfbhKBNyXODHGK5ONSo1qXtG

According to which, all I have to do is *Copy the thumbnail code under the Share tab*. Unfortunately, I can't seem to find any *thumbnail code* under the *Share tab*.

I also couldn't find any Y!Screen api on http://developer.yahoo.com/everything.html that could help me with this... ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using **[YQL](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/)** for cross domain data scraping along with **jQuery** is the solution that works.

Some of it is sound, some of it is hackish, but that's what scraping is all about I suppose.

The basis for this method was not done by me, but by using a tutorial for Facebook titled 
**[Create a Facebook-style Link Preview Using jQuery & YQL](http://ninjagirl.com/posts/2012/02/create-facebook-style-link-preview-using-jquery-yql)** written by Jocelyn Stretton.

Included in the modified JavaScript which serves as a starting point, you will have access and understand how to retrieve the following:

**1.** Yahoo! Screen Video Webpage Title 
**2.** Yahoo! Screen Thumbnail URL Link 
**3.** Yahoo! Screen Video URL Link 
**4.** Scrape Other `meta` Tag Content 
**5.** Yahoo Screen Video Embed Code provided by the Yahoo Screen Player itself.

[**DEMO in jsFiddle!**](http://jsfiddle.net/wzRrU/)

***EDIT: jsFiddle DEMO is no longer subdomain (regionally) dependent for video example.***

**EDIT 2:** For those that would like to see another tutorial based on this `.ajax() YQL` process, I've made two jsFiddles for Pinterest Data Scraping. You can see that SO Answer [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13814799/1195891) that discusses a lot more in detail for XPATH.

Comment: I tested without any locale specific subdomain and it seems to fetch all the info correctly.