# Identify & Extract the title/description of an Image (Data Scraping Pinterest)

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-scraping, bookmarklet, pinterest

How can Javascript/jQuery be used to identify the description or title corresponding to an image on a webpage with multiple images and descriptions?

The page title can be extracted very easily, but the title may not correspond to the image especially if there are many images present on the page

```
var title = document.title;
```

I believe this has been done successfully by Pinterest's Pin-it bookmarklet. I'm guessing it has to do with an algorithm to find the nearest `h1`, `h2`, `h3` or the image's `alt` attributes, then fallback to the `document.title` if the algorithm fails to identify the image's description on the page.

Any ideas greatly appreciated!

### EDIT

This is for data scraping other websites

Comment: yes you can find closest elements, or you can simply store the description/title in data attributes: `<img data-desc="My description" data-title="My Image Title" ...`

Comment: how can we find the closest elements that's a `h1`, `h2` or something that may be a description of the image?

Comment: It really depends on how your HTML is structured.

Comment: @Nyxynyx, Any thoughts on my Answer for [**jsFiddle Pinterest Data Scraping DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/4fmUR/) and [**Something Extra jsFiddle DEMO**](http://fiddle.jshell.net/r8axY/show)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OP has provided a great question to expand on. I recently created a jsFiddle for another [**SO Answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13776711/1195891) to data scrape **URL**, **Title**, and **Thumbnail** from the new **Yahoo! Screen Video Player** webpages.

I have just ***re-written that jsFiddle*** so it's Pinterest specific and have made direct use of **`Metatag Object Numbers`** (*more on that later*) which makes this jsFiddle very different from that one.

The overall process involves using **Yahoo's Query Language** along with jQuery `.ajax()` function to get the desired scraped data, usually available in the webpages source `metatag` section.

First, let me explain a few things.

The [**Pinterest Link**](http://pinterest.com/pin/40250990391375228/) that I will use will be a **direct link** to a pinned item. This means that webpage will contain the primary pinned item along with many other smaller pinned items, unlike the homepage which contains a multitude of only pinned items.

That [**Pinterest Link**](http://pinterest.com/pin/40250990391375228/) has for it's **Webpage Title** the pinned item's **`Title`** along with a few words that makes up the pinned item's **`Description`**. This most likely is not desired, and just the pinned item's **`Title`** is all that's needed.

Viewing the HTML Source Page for the [**Pinterest Link**](http://pinterest.com/pin/40250990391375228/) shows us the metatags that are currently used. Here's most of them:

```html
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="274266067164"/>

<meta property="og:site_name" content="Pinterest"/>
<meta property="og:type" content="pinterestapp:pin"/>
<meta property="og:url" content="http://pinterest.com/pin/40250990391375228/"/>
<meta property="og:title" content="FUNNY!!"/>
<meta property="og:description" content="Someone please do this."/>
<meta property="og:image" content="http://media-cache0.pinterest.com/upload/62980094758941134_yXgT124O_c.jpg"/>
<meta property="og:see_also" content="http://9gag.com/gag/2934786" />

<meta property="pinterestapp:pinboard" content="http://pinterest.com/amjo32/funny/"/>
<meta property="pinterestapp:pinner" content="http://pinterest.com/amjo32/"/>
<meta property="pinterestapp:source" content="http://9gag.com/gag/2934786"/>
<meta property="pinterestapp:likes" content="21"/>
<meta property="pinterestapp:repins" content="30"/>
<meta property="pinterestapp:comments" content="0"/>
<meta property="pinterestapp:actions" content="51"/>

<meta name="twitter:card" content="photo">
<meta name="twitter:url" content="http://pinterest.com/pin/40250990391375228/">
<meta name="twitter:site" content="@pinterest">

<meta name="google-site-verification" content="NvDayNupl7R0MDceeuRcs7xUf9yqUsxg6WGjEeRdAnc" />
<meta name="application-name" content="Pinterest" />
<meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#ffffff" />
```

As you can see, those `metatags` contains `og:title` and `og:image` data for which we are after.  It's then realized that these `og metatags` are a direct target which to perform the data scraping process.

To be sure, the `os:image` content link above is for the full image size version via `_c.jpg`.  The Thumbnail versions use `_b.jpg`. Essentially, you have two unique image sizes per pinned item.

Since the data scraping process does not return these `og property names`, only `Metatag Object Numbers`, we need to analyze the returned **`content`** associated with each `Metatag Object Number`.

Looking at the above `metatag` source, it's clear that the `image` will always be located at some place starting with **`http://media-`**. Those **`13`** characters are unique among all metatags, and therefore when that's matched, that entire URL is the **`image location`**.

Of course should Pinterest use more than one URL Template for there images, then things will need to be adjusted accordingly.

Looking at `og:title` you immediately realize that there are no unique string of characters in the ***content portion*** to indicate that this tag is the `image's title`. Therefore, assuming all metatags follow a template and will not change for some time, we will allocate this **`Metatag Object Number 7`** to provide the **`Pinterest Pinned Item's Image Title`**. To be clear, this number 7 is based on `.ajax()` and `YQL Results` from this scripts process, not the source HTML structure as seen above.

Again, if Pinterest changes there template for the `head section`, then adjustments may be required.

What follows now is an live **step by step tutorial** I wrote, based on data scraping techniques/script seen in this online [article](http://ninjagirl.com/posts/2012/02/create-facebook-style-link-preview-using-jquery-yql).

[**jsFiddle Pinterest Data Scraping DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/4fmUR/)

---

**Tip:**
Although not demonstrated, at your disposal is a **numeric value** for **total found Metatags**, which can be checked against a predetermined value for what the page ***should*** contain, indicating the `head section` has changed. For example, the current metatag count is `25` items. If the returned value is **not** equal to this value on any other **Pinterest Pinned Item** webpage, you know there is a different `head section` in use... which may affect the script since it ***expects only 25*** and calls two of them directly by it's **`Metatag Object Number`**.

---

**Something extra:**
If your curious on how to retrieve the current Pinterest Pinned ITEMS as seen on the homepage, first understand how this jsFiddle DEMO works. Then, you'll need to make your own jsFiddle version for testing and use the *Pinterest Homepage URL* along with changing the **`XPATH`** in the **`.ajax()`** call to data scrape only the **`relevant div's`** in the  **`body section`**. To learn more about `XPATH basics`, click [**HERE**](http://bit.ly/X3NVpf). Then you can understand: [**XPATH for Select Divs in Body on YQL Playground**](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/?q=SELECT%20*%20FROM%20html%20WHERE%20url%3D%22http%3A//pinterest.com/%22%20AND%20xpath%3D%22//body/div%5B@class%3D%27BoardLayout%27%5D/div%5B@id%3D%27ColumnContainer%27%5D/div%5B@class%3D%27pin%27%5D/div%5B@class%3D%27PinHolder%27%5D/a%22).

For example, the `body section` contains a ***maximum total*** of **50 pin's** in this format:

```html
 "href": "/pin/15833036160340477/"
```

Those `href fragments` will serve as a starting point in recreating the URL's. **Important note:** Some pins may be **`repins`** which means you will have less than 50 pins returned.

For those that read this far, here it is:

[**Something Extra jsFiddle DEMO**](http://fiddle.jshell.net/r8axY/show).

Here is an improved [**XPATH for Select Divs in Body on YQL Playground**](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/?q=SELECT%20*%20FROM%20html%20WHERE%20url%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fpinterest.com%2F%22%20AND%20xpath%3D%22%2F%2Fbody%2F%2Fdiv%5B%40class%3D'PinHolder'%5D%2Fa%22), but do understand how the longer one above works.

---

**Also see my other Pinterest SO Answers for:**

[**Custom Pinterest button for custom URL (Text-Link, Image, or Both)**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11488760/1195891)

[**How can I duplicate Pinterest website's modal effect?**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11253923/1195891)

Answer (score 0):

The best answer is: Look at how Pinterest does it.

For jQuery, look at "closest" function.

Here is just some quick and dirty untested code to give you a starting point for thinking about this, but this is very open ended question and the intelligence in your code can be as complex and robust or as simple as you want it to be.

```
$('img').each(function() {

    var title = $(this).prop('alt') || $(this).prop('title') || $(this).closest('h1,h2,h3').text();

   // do something with title

});​
```