# embed vimeo on my site with full video and thumbnails

Tags: php, xml, embed, vimeo

I want to embed vimeo like when you go to video->my videos->'click on one of them'
Now you see you video (it should also autostart) and thumbnails on the right side.

How can I embed this to my site in exactly the same way?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you hover over the video, there will be an "Embed" button. Click it and get the HTML.
And add "?autoplay=true" behind it for the autoplay.

So basically, insert this: http://player.vimeo.com/video/22541365?autoplay=true into an iframe.

Comment: Thumbnails can be done according to this answered question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1361149/get-img-thumbnails-from-vimeo

Comment: Ok so I need all thumbnails to be on the right side, and when you click one the video on the left will change.
Doens't look easy but I'll try