# Upload video details with vimeo advanced Api

Tags: php, api, thumbnails, vimeo

I want to know if is there a way to upload the tumbnails with its video using the APIs Advanced API /Upload API of VIMEO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I sent an email to the api developers community to ask about this point and the answer was :

> The advanced api does not currently support assigning thumbnails to videos. We will look into adding this feature in the future, but I can not give you a time frame at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

I am giving an answer by using PHP language.

- This library can be used for vimeo api integration:

  https://github.com/vimeo/vimeo-php-lib
- After uploading videos, try below solution to create thumbnails for videos:

  [Get img thumbnails from Vimeo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1361149/get-img-thumbnails-from-vimeo)

Comment: My problem here is not about how to upload thumbs associated with the video but, how to set it from the API ( the advanced api using PHP)

Answer (score 0):

I'm using latest Vimeo API's.
I tried this and it worked for me.

```
$lib = new \Vimeo\Vimeo($client_id, $client_secret);
$lib->setToken($access_token);

$video_uri = $lib->upload('video.mp4', false);

$metadata = array(
    'name' => "Video Title",
    'description' => "Description comes here"
);
$response = $lib->request($video_uri, $metadata, 'PATCH');
```