# Get vine video id using php

Tags: php

I need to get the vine video id from the url

so the output from link like this

> https://vine.co/v/bXidIgMnIPJ

be like this

> bXidIgMnIPJ

I tried to use code form other question here for Vimeo **(NOT VINE)**
*[Get img thumbnails from Vimeo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1361149/get-img-thumbnails-from-vimeo)*

This what I tried to use but I did not succeed

```
$url = 'https://vine.co/v/bXidIgMnIPJ';

preg_replace('~^https://(?:www\.)?vine\.co/(?:clip:)?(\d+)~','$1',$url)
```

Comment: regex is overkill. You just need everything after the last slash.

Comment: sure, if you don't need to validate that a link is correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[basename](http://www.php.net/basename) maybe?

```
<?php
$url = 'https://vine.co/v/bXidIgMnIPJ';
var_dump(basename($url));
```

http://codepad.org/vZiFP27y

Comment: Excuse me if my question is stupid, Why the output not just the video id?

Comment: I am just using var_dump to show the result of the basename function. You could just say `$id = basename($url);` and you would have the id.

Comment: are you referring to the extra `string(11)...etc` in the output? That is from var_dump. [var_dump](http://www.php.net/var_dump) will dump some information about  variable. In this case, the variable was a "string" that was "11" characters in length with the value of "bXidIgMnIPJ". var_dump is very useful way of outputting data about a variable. If the string was empty, echo or print would just output nothing. var_dump actually would say `string(0) ""` which tells me more. var_dump also works with all variable types (boolean, object, array...etc).

Comment: Thank You, I wish you all the best :)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming it will always be in that format, you can just split the url by the `/` delimiter. Regex is not needed for a simple url such as this.

```
$id = end(explode('/', $url));
```

Answer (score 1):

Referring to as the question is asked here is a solution for `preg_replace`:

```
$s = 'https://vine.co/v/bXidIgMnIPJ';
$new_s = preg_replace('/^.*\//','',$s);
echo $new_s;
// => bXidIgMnIPJ
```

or if you need to validate that an input string is indeed a link to vine.co :

```
$new_s = preg_replace('/^(https?:\/\/)?(www\.)?vine\.co.*\//','',$s);
```

I don't know if that `/v/` part is always present or is it always `v`... if it is then it may also be added to regex for stricter validation:

```
$new_s = preg_replace('/^(https?:\/\/)?(www\.)?vine\.co\/v\//','',$s);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I am using:

```
function getVineId($url) {
  preg_match("#(?<=vine.co/v/)[0-9A-Za-z]+#", $url, $matches);
  if (isset($matches[0])) {
    return $matches[0];
  }
  return false;
}
```

I used a [look-behind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to ensure "vine.co/v/" always precedes the ID, while ignoring if the url is HTTP or HTTPS (or if it lacks a protocol altogether). It assumes the ID is alphanumeric, of any length. It will ignore any characters or parameters after the id (like Google campaign tracking parameters, etc).

I used the ["#" delimiter](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php) so I wouldn't have to escape the forward slashes (/), for a cleaner look.

Answer (score 0):

explode the string with '/' and the last string is what you are looking for :) Code:

```
$vars = explode("/",$url);
echo $vars[count($vars)-1];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$url = 'https://vine.co/v/b2PFre2auF5';
$regex = '/^http(?:s?):\/\/(?:www\.)?vine\.co\/v\/([a-zA-Z0-9]{1,13})$/';
preg_match($regex,$url,$m);
print_r($m);

1. b2PFre2auF5
```