# How to get album list from vimeo

Tags: javascript, php, api, vimeo

Currently working on a project where I have hosted all the video files to vimeo server.

Now I want to display the thumbnail of those videos on my page, using vimeo API. So far there is API available to fetch users data after authenticating them using application while this is not the case here.

How can I display those videos list as thumbnails on my page, any quick fix will be appreciated?

Comment: Perhaps this answer will get what you need http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1361149/get-img-thumbnails-from-vimeo

Comment: @Ma'moonAl-Akash your suggestion is for images only, I want to have the whole list of videos from my vimeo albums.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this URL to get video details in JSON `http://vimeo.com/api/v2/video/VIDEO_ID.json` (Also available is XML: `http://vimeo.com/api/v2/video/VIDEO_ID.xml`)

Example: http://vimeo.com/api/v2/video/6271487.json

Then, check the values `thumbnail_small`, `thumbnail_medium` and `thumbnail_large`.

**Update**: To get the thumbnail for private video:

Download [Viemo PHP library](https://github.com/vimeo/vimeo-php-lib). Then use this code:

```
$video_id = 'VIDEO_ID';
$key = 'YOUR_CONSUMER_KEY';
$secret = 'YOUR_CONSUMER_SECRET';

require_once('vimeo.php');
$vimeo = new phpVimeo($key, $secret);
$video = $vimeo->call('vimeo.videos.getInfo', array('video_id' => $video_id));

$img_small = $video->video[0]->thumbnails->thumbnail[0]->_content;
$img_medium = $video->video[0]->thumbnails->thumbnail[1]->_content;
$img_large = $video->video[0]->thumbnails->thumbnail[2]->_content;
```

Comment: what about private videos ?

Comment: thanks for the code now I will work around for albums and list :)

Answer (score 1):

Get list of all albums for a user (obviously oauth protected):

http://developer.vimeo.com/apis/advanced/methods/vimeo.albums.getAll

Comment: this is outdated now, link is broken.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the documentation Vimeo offers, this is what you should be using:

https://developer.vimeo.com/api/reference/videos#get_videos

in combo with:
https://developer.vimeo.com/api/reference/videos#get_video_thumbnail

I'm not going to write you the code as it is very easy, and I would remove from you all the fun :-)

Comment: links are broken

Comment: @ChaudhryWaqas With littel effort you can suggest an edit, i'll update the answer with the new information