# vimeo thumbnail : is it really the only way to get a simple thumbnail?

Tags: integration, vimeo

I was looking for a simple way to get thumbnails for some videos on Vimeo and the only way to do that seems to be to use Vimeo API.

The problem is not that it's to complicate for me to do something like :

```
$thumb = unserialize(file_get_contents('http://vimeo.com/api/v2/video/'.$VIDEO_ID.'/php'));
echo '<img src="'.$thumb[0]['thumbnail_medium'].'">';
```

But if you need to get 50 thumbnails, it will be a little bit long comparing to :

```
echo '<img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/'.$VIDEO_ID.'/1.jpg">';
```

don't you think so ?

is that really the only way or is it a joke ?

Comment: There is another post that covers this more in-depth. I ended up using the javascript solution for my thumbnails and haven't had any issues. [See the Post Here.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1361149/get-img-thumbnails-from-vimeo)

Comment: Hi CJdriver and thanks for your answer,

I've read this post and that's why I posted too, I've made tests with all those solutions with an array of 50 urls and it tooks 20 seconds to show the page...

It tooks 1 seconds to do the same with direct urls of the thumbnails on youtube...

I just say that's it's a bit complicated to get thumbnails witch should be in a logically named directory.

Comment: I agree, and that's one of the negatives of Vimeo in my opinion. Have you tried contacting them directly? If enough people complain they might change something. 
I use it for 3 thumbnails so I've been lucky on having reasonable page load times.

Comment: Thanks for your answer,
I haven't find any way to contact them to give some opinion on their website...
They say that if we have a problem, we should go to stack Overflow and that's what I did.
I hope some of them developers will have a look here ;-)
Have a nice day !