# Show thumbnails from private vimeo videos

Tags: api, thumbnails, vimeo

I built a website with videos from vimeo. I want to show thumbnails from those videos on my site, but the normal [API access won't help](https://developer.vimeo.com/apis/simple#xml-response-format).
The videos are private and can be accessed only in [this site](http://psychomaster.co.il/)
How can I get those thumbnails?
Thanks

Comment: I tried using C# API from [here](http://www.robgreen.me/post/Getting-Started-With-The-Vimeo-API-in-C.aspx) and had no luck.

Comment: Solved this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1361149/get-img-thumbnails-from-vimeo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a class with options for Large, Medium and Small images.

```
 namespace VimeoWrapper
   {
    public enum ThumbnailSize { Large, Medium, Small };    
public enum VimeoErrors { NotFound, SizeNotExist, NetError }
    public static class VimeoHelper
    {
        public static string GetVideoThumbnail(string videoid, ThumbnailSize tns = ThumbnailSize.Large)
        {
            string query = String.Format("https://api.vimeo.com/me/videos/{0}", videoid);

            string accessToken = "Token from API";

            WebClient wc = new WebClient();

            wc.Headers.Add("Authorization", "bearer " + accessToken);

            string result;

            try
            {
                result = wc.DownloadString(query);
            }
            catch (System.Net.WebException e)
            {
                return VimeoErrors.NotFound.ToString();
            }

            try
            {
                dynamic jsonResult = JValue.Parse(result);
                switch (tns)
                {
                    case ThumbnailSize.Large:
                        return jsonResult.pictures.sizes[5].link;
                    case ThumbnailSize.Medium:
                        return jsonResult.pictures.sizes[3].link;
                    case ThumbnailSize.Small:
                        return jsonResult.pictures.sizes[1].link;
                }
            }
            catch (JsonReaderException e)
            {
                return VimeoErrors.SizeNotExist.ToString();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return VimeoErrors.NetError.ToString();
            }

            return VimeoErrors.NetError.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The API you linked is an old, deprecated API. The new API (developer.vimeo.com/api) will give you all the information you need.

You can learn more on the getting started page: https://developer.vimeo.com/api/start

Once you have a token, you can access your images from the direct video endpoint (https://api.vimeo.com/videos/{video_id}), Or from a collection of videos (such as https://api.vimeo.com/me/videos for your videos, or https://api.vimeo.com/channels/{channel_id}/videos for a channel's videos)

Comment: Thanks
Do you know which .Net API should I use for that? there are two versions:
[VimeoDotNet3](https://github.com/saeedafshari/VimeoDotNet3)
[vimeo-dot-net](https://github.com/scommisso/vimeo-dot-net)

Comment: I tried using the first one,  but I can't figure out how to use it. I don't need a multi user app so I don't have any redirect url.

Comment: Those are both developed by third party developers. You will probably have better luck reaching out to them through their public support channels (often listed on the project page)