# How to get thumbnail url from https://player.vimeo.com/video/{$videoid} in php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I have a question how to retrieve vimeo thumbnail images from player.vimeo.com url . can any one have any idea? How to fix these.
I have retrieve thubnail url for normal vimeo url. But that method is not working for player.vimeo.com.

I have done for normal vimeo url. the code is like :

```
<?php
$video_url = 'https://vimeo.com/178494888';
$video_id = explode("/",$video_url)[3];
$video_link = 'https://player.vimeo.com/video/'.$video_id;
$img_url = 'https://vimeo.com/api/v2/video/'.$video_id.'.php';
$video_img_array = unserialize(file_get_contents($img_url));
$video_img = $video_img_array[0]['thumbnail_large'];
echo $video_img;
?>
```

Please can you help me for 'https://player.vimeo.com/video/{video_id}'.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1361149/get-img-thumbnails-from-vimeo

Comment: @Armin , I have go through that solution... But not working for player.vimeo.com