# How do I get all the preview thumbnail images of a Vimeo video

Tags: vimeo, vimeo-api, vimeo-player

I want to show all the preview thumbnail images of a Vimeo on a pages. I'm the owner of a Vimeo Pro account but I don't see any options or an API call to get them. A file with the timestamps and an image url would be good enough.

I can't run a script to generate them myself so I was wondering if anyone found such an option?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get img thumbnails from Vimeo?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1361149/get-img-thumbnails-from-vimeo)

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about the preview thumbnails that appear when you seek on a video, those are not currently available via the API.

I'll make a note though, and see if we can add them in the future.

Comment: Hi Dasron, Is it added now?