# Get thumbnail image of Vimeo video WITHOUT making a request to the Vimeo API

Tags: vimeo, vimeo-api

Looking for a way to obtain a thumbnail image of a Vimeo video WITHOUT (I repeat, WITHOUT) having to do a REST request to the Vimeo API?

(Unfortunately, the following "answer" is over 10 years old and does NOT answer this question: [Get img thumbnails from Vimeo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1361149/get-img-thumbnails-from-vimeo))

Nearly all video providers allow you to obtain a thumbnail image of a video by simply supplying the video ID within a specific URL path (i.e.: YouTube, Matterport, iGuide, etc.)

To be clear - I am NOT looking for a "solution" that uses Javascript or requires a request to be made to the Vimeo API - just a specific URL that can return a thumbnail given a Vimeo video ID.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I also emailed Vimeo API support, and below is the "official" response I received from their support group:

> Hi there,
>
> Thanks for your interest in the Vimeo API! Full documentation of the
> Vimeo API can be found on our Developer Site:
>
> https://developer.vimeo.com/api/guides/start
>
> **Sorry, but it's not possible to get a video's thumbnail links without
> first making a request to one of our APIs** (oEmbed or our full-fledged
> REST API). You can learn about these APIs here:
>
> https://developer.vimeo.com/api/oembed/videos
>
> https://developer.vimeo.com/api/guides/start

So - no way to get a thumbnail of a Vimeo video without making a REST request.  Too bad.

**Update: 2-Oct-2021**
See @Parthiban post - Vimeo has updated their service / documentation:
https://developer.vimeo.com/api/oembed/videos

Answer (score 6):

You can use the Vimeo oEmbed method, which gives a JSON response with the video's basic meta-information including thumbnails. Which doesn't require an authentication method like Vimeo API.

More details in the official documentation here: https://developer.vimeo.com/api/oembed/videos

Answer (score 6):

Check out https://vumbnail.com/

You can simply pass in the id of the video in the url and it will respond with the thumbnail image.

https://vumbnail.com/358629078.jpg

You can also request certain sizes as per the documentation. This appears to be made by a third party so I can't say whether it is well supported and reliable but it appears to do what it claims to do as of the time that I'm writing this answer. Best of luck.